# Properly linking 2 tables deep with cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to link up my Models properly to achieve the following:

I have 3 tables, Clients -> Initiatives -> Milestones.

In Clients I have:

```
public $hasMany = array( 'Initiative'  );
```

In Initiative model I have:

```
public $belongsTo = 'Client';
public $hasMany = 'Milestone'
```

And Milestones has:

```
public $belongsTo = 'Initiative';
```

Using public $recursive = 2; in the Client model I am able to get the Milestones nested in the Initiatives of the results, so they look like this...

```
array(2) {
["Client"]=>
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "Company"
 }
["Initiative"]=>
array(5) {  
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["client_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["Milestone"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["initiative_id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
       }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["initiative_id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
      }
```

Or to use a short hand:

```
result
  [client]
  [initiative]
        [milestone]
```

But what I want, for convenience, is for the model to return the the Milestones as it's own array not nested in initiative. So,

```
result
  [client]
  [initiative]
  [milestone]
```

I think I need to set up a some sort of custom query in my model.  How can I do this?

Comment: There could be many 'initiatives', and therefore milestones must be nested below initiatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this could not be possible because

A Client  --- hasMany ---> Initiatives

An Initiative --- hasMany ---> Milestones

so if you get a client info then multiple initiatives will retrieves with that, and if you will get an initiative then multiple milestones will be there.

If you still want to combine all the milestones and displayed at the first level then you have to traverse the array values and retrieve the milestones manually.